# Video texture on a cube

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures

Trying to put a simple video on a cube as a texture, and the result is just nothing:)

```
video = document.createElement('video');
video.width = 320;
video.height = 320;
video.autoplay = true;
video.loop = true;
video.src = 'video.mp4'


var videoTexture = new THREE.Texture(video);
videoTexture.needsupdate = true;


  var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry( 10, 10, 10, 1, 1, 1 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ map: videoTexture }));
  scene.add(cube);
```

If I add `color: '#fff'` instead of `map: videoTexture` I see a white square, so the cube is adding, so it is something with the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an indication that the video is playing? You also need a check in your `render()` function:

```
if ( video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA ) {

    if ( videoTexture ) videoTexture.needsUpdate = true;

}
```

For quality/speed you can also add these to your definition:

```
videoTexture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
videoTexture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
videoTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
videoTexture.generateMipmaps = false;
```

Comment: Yes, video is playing. I tried also a regular video put to DOM and getting it by `document.getElementById()` and result was the same. Very strange...

Comment: actually the `video.readystate` helped. My sloppy code fault. Thank You!